# Creating user on sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

i'm having some problems after createUser() on environment.
Maybe it could be some misconception about sharded cluster.

So.
I've logged in MongoS with my admin user and run the statement to create user

```
use mydatabase
db.createUser( 
  {
    user: "myreaduser",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [{role: "read", db: "mydatabase"}]
  }
)
```

After this i logged sucessfully with this user on MongoS.
I could see the user as admin, running db.getUser("myreaduser") for instance.

But my problem is about mongod, I've failed to log with this user on mongod.

```
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

I checked if the user was created on mongod, but it wasn't.

In my understanding it should have to been created, because i used mongoS to run this statement through the cluster.

Is this understanding about mongo cluster wrong?
So, should I have to create user in mongoS and mongod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

> So, should I have to create user in mongoS and mongod?

Correct! These are completely separate database users.

The database users used to connect via a mongos are stored in the [admin database user of the config server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#sharded-cluster-users). In comparison, [Shard Local Users](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#shard-local-users) are created directly on the shard itself and are local to the shard.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this question for me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please feel free to accept the answer if you feel it answered you question.